# Radio and Checkbox button state cleared when clicking browser's back button

Tags: html, checkbox, radio-button, microsoft-edge

i have a problem with regards to checkbox button state when navigating to next page then click back button of Edge (MS) browser.

While digging for information about this problem, i came across this [bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4525797/). Since 2015, it has no updates. To date, is there any workarounds with this issue?

The use case is below;

1. User access a page
2. Tick's a checkbox or radio button
3. Navigate to another page (either via address bar or clicking a link via  tag)
4. Once another page has been loaded, Click Edge's back button (or Alt + Left Arrow)
5. Previous state/value of checkbox or radio button must persist or preserved.

Right now, state/value is cleared when navigating back to page via Back button of Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I reproduce the problem on my side, the state/value if checkbox or radio button is not preserved in Edge browser. It is a known issue, I have feedback this issue to Edge Platform.

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to use [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (such as: local storage or session storage) to store the state/value, then, then page reload, reset these state/value.

Code as below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function myfunction() {
            //check whether the browser support storage
            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.

                if (sessionStorage.checkboxstatus) {
                    document.getElementById("Checkbox1").checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("Checkbox1").checked = false;
                }

                if (sessionStorage.radiostatus) {
                    document.getElementById("Radio1").checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("Radio1").checked = false;
                }

                //checkbox click event: use session storage to store the state
                document.getElementById("Checkbox1").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (document.getElementById("Checkbox1").checked) {
                        sessionStorage.checkboxstatus = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        sessionStorage.checkboxstatus = false;
                    }
                });
                //radio button click event: to store the state.
                document.getElementById("Radio1").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (document.getElementById("Radio1").checked) {
                        sessionStorage.radiostatus = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        sessionStorage.radiostatus = false;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
                alert("No web storage support");
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myfunction();">
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" />
    <a href="/HtmlPage2.html">Link</a>
</body>
```

the result like this:

[image]